# applying css for <li> tag, ASP.Net which is in master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

Hi all I would like to apply `css` for `<li>` tag which is in master page dynamically from code behind this is my design

```
<div id="primary_nav">
    <ul>
       <li class="left active" id="nav_discussion" runat="server">
           <a title="Go to Forums" href="">
               Forums
           </a>
       </li>
       <li class="left" id="nav_members" runat="server">
           <a title="Go to Member List" href="Members.aspx">
               Members
           </a>
       </li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

[image]
In my content page I accessed `<li>` as follows

```
Control li = Page.Master.FindControl("nav_members");
```

But I am unable to apply the required `css` here can some one help me

Comment: `<li class="left" id="nav_members" runat="server">` I make this as server control na?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, your `Control` is of type `HtmlGenericControl` which does not contain a property for `CssClass`.

You will need to cast your control to type HtmlGenericControl. e.g.

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl li = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl) this.Page.Master.FindControl("nav_members");
```

This will then give you two choices to apply the style to the element. You can either use the `Style` property or the `Attributes` property.

The `Style` property will allow you to add inline styling to the element e.g.:

```
li.Style.Add("Color", "Black");
```

This will render the element with:

```
style="color:red;"
```

Your other option is to use the `Attributes` property which will allow you to add the `class`.

```
li.Attributes.Add("class", "nameofyourclass");
```

Read more about the [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you find the control then use following to add css

```
 Control li = Page.Master.FindControl("nav_members");
 li .Style.Add("float", "left");
```

If you want to override some property then you can use

```
  li .Style.Add("width", "100px !important");
```

etc.Here is a good link
[What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)

Here is a similar question
[C# - How to change HTML elements attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186918/c-sharp-how-to-change-html-elements-attributes)

### Edit 1.

You need to cast it in a html generic control first

```
 HtmlGenericControl  li = (HtmlGenericControl)(Page.Master.FindControl("nav_members"));
 li .Style.Add("width", "100px !important");
```

Comment: `li .Style.Add("float", "left");` after `.` I am unable to get `Style` or `attributes.add` that's why I asked

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
nav_members.Attributes.Add("class", value);
```

Comment: In a normal web page this works, but I would like to call this from master page